# How to show git log history from a given commit backwards

Tags: git

I am investigating the history of a git repository to check for changes but do not want to bisect since I do not need to test (just see where/when some files changed, then inspect with git show).
Is there a way to tell git to show log from a commit backwards since the beginning of time?

I could only find ways to show HEAD to commit or commit to HEAD (HEAD being default also for the  end of revision ranges).

Edit for clarity:
Given

```
c0--c1--c2--....--c100--c101--c102--HEAD
```

Something like

```
git log --from_here_backwards c101
```

Which should give history starting from c100 (or even c101) backwards towards c0

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--reverse` option to git log. With path-options you can throwout not needed commits.

```
git log --reverse <REV> -- <PATH/TO/FILES>
```

**edit after clerification of question:**

```
git log --reverse <c0>...<c100>
```

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I need, the commits should still be listed from the given one then listing most recent ones towards beginning of time. reverse shows them starting from the beginning of time which is definitely unpractical

Comment: you can still use the same revision clarification for git like without `--reverse`. Eg. `git log --reverse <REV> -- <PATH/TO/FILES>`

Comment: log  into manual pages of gitrevisions `man 7 gitrevisions` here is descibed how you can specify your revisions.

Comment: That would need knowing c0 in advance, which I think is not a fixed sha or has no label like HEAD

Comment: Ahhh, have you read the `gitrevisions` manualpage? If you omit c0 you can have all what you want :-) Try: `git log --reverse <c100>` ... by the way, this was my first answer.

Comment: Yes I have read before posting that if you omit any of the revisions HEAD is taken as default, not c0, hence no luck with this solution.